# Why don't I manage to enable connection on port 80 and 443?

Tags: linux, debian

My OS is Debian 8, the ports 443 and 80 are not opened as shown by the following command:

```
nc -zv 127.0.0.1 80
localhost [127.0.0.1] 80 (http) : Connection refused
```

I'm trying to open them with the following commands:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 --syn -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

but without success.
Please note that I don't have any firewall activated (`sudo ufw status verbose` gives `Status: inactive`).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you actually have anything *listening* on that port? Say, apache or nginx or lighttpd ? Use the `netstat -pat` command to see what if anything is listening on which TCP port(s)

Comment: Do you have something listening on those ports? The last of those `iptables` commands allows traffic that comes from port 80 on other systems, that's probably not what you want.

Comment: @Shadur `netstat -pat | grep 80` (and 443) prints nothing.  @Henrik indeed it is not what I want but how can I make the ports 80 and  443 of my localhost opened?

Comment: Then you have nothing listening on those ports. Then it's not surprising that you can't connect (there's nothing to connect to). What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: Then you don't have anything listening on those ports, which is why you get connection refused.

Comment: Debian does not automatically install a webserver unless you tell it to during installation. If you want to run one, use `apt-get install apache2` or `apt-get install nginx` or `apt-get install lighttpd`, as per taste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't running any software that listens on that port.

"Connection refused" is the standard response of a system when you try to connect to a port that has no service attached to it. It's basically the networking layer saying "Nothing here, go away."

If you want to run a webserver, you'll have to install one; debian has several available -- you can use `apt-get` to install whichever one you prefer.